# WSO2 integrator 6.1.0 clustering vs multiple node with load balancer

Tags: wso2, cluster-computing, load-balancing, wso2-esb

In reference to Integration Profile
what are the difference between:

1. configuring as a cluster 2 manager nodes(using hazelcast) with a load balancer in front ([according to the documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/Clustering+the+Integration+Profile))
2. configuring 2 non-clustered manager nodes with a lb in front (without intercomunication) and with shared registry

if the artifacts are deployed manually on every node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define schedule tasks, they will be exectuded on the 2 nodes. If you define JMS or VFS consumers, this is the same (there will be 2 consumers on the jms queue, ...). You can configure a JMS inbound endpoint to be executed only on one node in a cluster, but you have no way to do te same thing with two standalone WSO2 instances

However, you will not see any difference with http proxy services or API.

Comment: Thanks Jean-Michel for good info. Practically I use only hl7 proxy and API

Comment: It's correct share the registry between two standalone instances?

Comment: when you configure a cluster, you share "governance and config registry" and "user management database", but each node must have it's own local "data repository". I don't know if you can share the same gov registry between two node that will not join the same cluster without side effect, sorry

Comment: In addition to the answer of Jean-Michel, with the cluster mode, the schedule tasks (or inbound endpoints) will be dispatch to the other nodes in case one node is going down.